# android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS what kind of permission Normal? or Dangerous?

Tags: android, permissions

I have read [Dengerous permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html) and [Normal permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html) as well. but I didn't find this permission anywhere. I just want to know what kind of permission is it?

Answer (score 2):

WRITE_SETTINGS

added in API level 1
String WRITE_SETTINGS
Allows an application to read or write the system settings.

Note: If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission management screen. The app requests the user's approval by sending an intent with action ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS. The app can check whether it has this authorization by calling Settings.System.canWrite().

Protection level: signature

Constant Value: "android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"

Comment: Thank you! for your answer. I got it

Answer (score 1):

> **Special Permissions**
>   There are a couple of permissions that don't behave like normal and dangerous permissions. SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW and WRITE_SETTINGS are particularly sensitive, so most apps should not use them. If an app needs one of these permissions, it must declare the permission in the manifest, and send an intent requesting the user's authorization. The system responds to the intent by showing a detailed management screen to the user.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#perm-groups

Comment: Thank you, @Eselfar

Answer (score 1):

The protection level is signature. You must ask the user to be granted this permission if your API level is greater than or equal to 23.
 You can find the documentation on all permissions  [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html),
 and you can find the documentation for the permission you specified [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SETTINGS).